# iOS GoogleAnalytic continuously produce an exception

Tags: ios, exception, google-analytics

I'm currently using the last version of Google Analytics (v2.0)

I instantiate it the most common way in my appDelegate:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = NO;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 0;
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"..."];
```

But when i'm running the app it continuously produce this exception in logs:

```
An observer of NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification illegally threw an exception.  Objects saved = {
    deleted = "{(\n    <GAIHit: 0xc1cac50> (entity: GAIHit; id: 0xc160740 <x-coredata://8854889C-BE6C-49BB-BBA9-99465B86265E/GAIHit/p26> ; data: {\n    dispatchUrl = \"https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect\";\n    gaiVersion = \"2.0b4\";\n    parametersData = <62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050852 53542474 6f705824 6f626a65 63747358 24766572 73696f6e 59246172 63686976 6572>;\n    timestamp = \"2013-07-10 10:21:55 +0000\";\n})\n)}";
    inserted = "{(\n)}";
    updated = "{(\n)}";
} and exception = Object's persistent store is not reachable from this NSManagedObjectContext's coordinator with userInfo = (null)
```

It doesn't make the application crash, but it's very verbose and pollute my logs.

Moreover, it seems to work, because GA logs says:

```
-[GAIDispatcher dispatchComplete:withStartTime:withRetryNumber:withResponse:withData:withError:] (GAIDispatcher.m:415) DEBUG: Successfully dispatched hit /GAIHit/p51 (0 retries).
```

Any idea to stop these logs?

Comment: In your context changed handler (which you register for `contextChanged:` notification) you can check whether the notification came from your Core Data session or not like this: `if (((NSManagedObjectContext *)notification.object).persistentStoreCoordinator != self.persistentStoreCoordinator) return;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From GAM documentation:

> If your app uses the CoreData framework: responding to a notification,
>   e.g. NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, from the Google
>   Analytics CoreData object may result in an exception. Instead, Apple
>   recommends filtering CoreData notifications by specifying the managed
>   object context as a parameter to your listener. Learn more from Apple.

I guess that is your case

Comment: Wow. Well spotted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I can't tell you how befuddled this was making me — all I did was pass my main context in as the object when binding to the notification, and that worked. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: How I can do that? I mean filter the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification I'm new on that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should merge changes only from your managed object contexts, not from any other contexts created by the third-party libraries.

However filtering by contexts implies storing somewhere the list of all your background contexts. I've found easier solution: instead of comparing the context with your list of contexts it's sufficient just to check whether the context was created for your PersistentStoreCoordinator:

```
- (void) managedObjectContextDidSaveNotification: (NSNotification *) notification {
    NSManagedObjectContext * context = notification.object;
    if (context != self.managedObjectContextForMainThread) {
        if (context.persistentStoreCoordinator == self.persistentStoreCoordinator) {
            [context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
        }
    }
}
```